# how to get record based on url in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

i have indexing based on URL,BODYTEXT,TITLE etc. i want to seach based on URL my code is working but it is given only exact URL match record. For example :
record 1 :
url:http://example.com/example/index.php
content: example is good in lucene and bla bla
host:example.com
title: welcome to example

record 2:
url :http://example.com/
content:example is one of best solution
host;example.com
title :welcome to example

it is give only record 2 because my url is http://example.com/ so how to get record 1 and record 2 by url http://example.com/ because  http://example.com/example/index.php is also
part of http://example.com/.

My code  for searching ->

```
                 Term term = new Term("URL", siteUrl.toLowerCase());
         Query query1 = new TermQuery(term);
         BooleanQuery booleanQuery.add(query1,BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
                 TopDocs hits = is.search(booleanQuery, 50000);
```

code for indexing

```
  private Document createLuceneDocument(HTMLDocument htmlDocument) 
  {
    Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new Field("URL", htmlDocument.getUrl().toLowerCase(), Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED,Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));

    return document;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A TermQuery makes an exact match only.  It is the simplest kind of search.  There is another kind of query called PrefixQuery that will match a field that starts with a value you specify.  Is that what you're looking for?  If you want to match on any part of a URL, then you need to break up the URL and index the components in separate fields, or else use an analyzer that can effectively do that during the indexing (and searching) process.